# pointcloud_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, pointcloud-to-laserscan, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need the package pointcloud_to_laserscan (I can not use depthimage_to_laserscan because I have to specify the min and max height of the points).

I tried to catkinize the package but I couldn't. I tried to reproduce it myself for ROS Hydro but it was impossible.

Has anyone this package (or any other similar version) working on catkin systems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191407/pointcloud_to_laserscan/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the package without converting it to catkin using the old rosbuild infrastructure buiding from source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-08-27**:
How can I do that??